# Use projectile-find-file after switching to a notes file that's not in the project directory

Tags: projectile

I have a "home file" with a keyboard shortcut of C-c h
(used for writing quick notes, org style)

How can I still use projectile-find-file, after switching to my notes file?

The issue is the notes reside in a non project git repo at ~/notes/,
and on any given day I might be working on ~/project1/
~/project2 or ~/project3

So when I invoke projectile-find-file, I am shown files in my notes folders,
when what I really want to see is the app/models, app/controllers, Gemfile, etc in the ~/projectN folder of the "project of the day"

The "project of the day" is the "primary project I'm focussing on for that day". It's a constant for any given day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `projectile-switch-project`. Once you've selected your project, it invokes another action, which by default is `projectile-find-file` (but you can set it to any function with no arguments).

Another option is to use `projectile-find-file-in-known-projects`, which will let you find files across all of your projects.

(By the way, I hope you're using `helm-projectile`, it's great!)